Issue with Sending Final Checkmate Move to Both Players in Chess Game Using chess.js npm Package
I  am working on a chess game using the chess.js npm package and WebSockets to handle communication between players. The problem I am facing is when a player makes the final checkmating move, the game over message is sent to both players, but the move object is still being sent to the opponent player, even after the game is over. This results in an invalid move error because the game state is already finished.
Backend Code:
export class Game {
    
    constructor(player1, player2) {
        this.player1 = player1;
        this.player2 = player2;
        this.board = new Chess();
        this.moveCount = 0;
        this.startTime = new Date();
        this.gameover = false;

        this.player1.send(JSON.stringify({
            type: INIT_GAME,
            payload: {
                color: "white"
            }
        }))
        this.player2.send(JSON.stringify({
            type: INIT_GAME,
            payload: {
                color: "black"
            }
        }))
    }

    game_over(move) {
        // Check if game is over
        if (this.board.isGameOver()) {
            this.gameover = true;
            const winnerColor = this.board.turn() === "w" ? "black" : "white";
            const winner = winnerColor === "black" ? this.player2 : this.player1;
            const loser = winner === this.player1 ? this.player2 : this.player1;
            this.player1.send(JSON.stringify({
                type: GAME_OVER,
                payload: move,
                result: {
                    winner: winnerColor,
                    message: winner === this.player1 ? "You win!" : "Opponent wins!"
                }
            }))
            this.player2.send(JSON.stringify({
                type: GAME_OVER,
                payload: move,
                result: {
                    winner: winnerColor,
                    message: loser === this.player1 ? "You win!" : "Opponent wins!"
                }
            }))
            console.log("result sent to both players")
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    makeMove(socket, move) {
        // validations
        // restricting player 1 and 2 after playing 1 move
        if (this.moveCount % 2 === 0 && socket !== this.player1) {
            return;
        }
        if (this.moveCount % 2 === 1 && socket !== this.player2) {
            return;
        }

        // Is the move valid
        try {
            this.board.move(move);            
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            return;
        }

        if (this.game_over(move)) {
            console.log("inside this.game_over")
            return;
        }

        if (!this.gameover) {
            if (this.moveCount % 2 === 0) {
                this.player2.send(JSON.stringify({
                    type: MOVE,
                    payload: move
                }))
            } else {
                this.player1.send(JSON.stringify({
                    type: MOVE,
                    payload: move
                }))
            }
            this.moveCount++;
        }

        // send the updated board to both players
    }
}

Frontend Code (React):
const Game = () => {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const socket = useSocket();
    const [chess, setChess] = useState(new Chess());
    const [board, setBoard] = useState(chess.board());
    const [started, setStarted] = useState(false);
    const [winner, setWinner] = useState("");
    const [disable, setDisable] = useState(false);
    const [resultmsg, setResultmsg] = useState("");
    const resultDialogBox = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!socket) {
            return;
        }
        socket.onmessage = (event) => {
            const msg = JSON.parse(event.data);
            console.log(msg);
            switch (msg.type) {
                case INIT_GAME:
                    setBoard(chess.board());
                    setStarted(true);
                    console.log("Game Initialized")
                    break;

                case MOVE:
                    const move = msg.payload;
                    chess.move(move);
                    setBoard(chess.board());
                    console.log("Move made")
                    break;

                case GAME_OVER:
                    const finalMove = msg.payload;
                    setBoard(chess.board());
                    chess.move(finalMove);
                    setWinner(msg.result.winner);
                    setResultmsg(msg.result.message)
                    if (resultDialogBox.current) {
                        setTimeout(() => {
                            resultDialogBox.current.showModal();
                        }, 2000);
                    }
                    console.log(`winner is ${msg.result.winner}`)
                    console.log("Game Over")
                    break;
            
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }, [socket])
}

